# como hace captura de pantalla desde un picturebox y mostrarlo en otro picturebox en c#

Tags: c#, screenshot

he intentado hacer captura desde un picturebox1 y mostrarlo en un picturebox2 al hacer clic en un botón.
pero al realizarlo no me muestra area exacta del picturebox1, en cambio captura otra parte de la pantalla.

he intentado con este Código en visual estudio 2022, tengo windows11.

```
    private void btOCR_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Obtener la posición y el tamaño del PictureBox
        Point pictureBoxLocation = pictureBox1.PointToScreen(Point.Empty);
        Size pictureBoxSize = pictureBox1.Size;

        // Capturar el área de la pantalla correspondiente al PictureBox
        Bitmap screenshot = new Bitmap(pictureBoxSize.Width, pictureBoxSize.Height);
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(screenshot))
        
        g.CopyFromScreen(pictureBoxLocation, Point.Empty, pictureBoxSize);
       
        // Mostrar la captura en el PictureBox
        pictureBox2.Image = screenshot;
    }


}
```

}